# Setting a reminder without a time

Tags: iphone, mac

I usually have Siri set my reminders for me and sometimes Siri misses the time. I have to go in and edit in the time, but I was wondering if I don't do that (i.e., reminder has a date but no time), do I still get notified on that day, and if so, what time would I get notified?

Answer (score 2):

- If you don't set a date - you don't get any notifications
- If you set a date - you do get notified at the time specified in Reminders.app preferences, on the iPhone you can change all-day notifications in Settings -> Reminders -> All-day reminders.
- If you set a date & time - you do get notified at the specific time.

Siri is a nice way to add reminders. It's not perfect, sometimes speech-to-text misses. If you are using Mac OS, you could try entering your reminders with the keyboard using this app https://apps.apple.com/en/app/menu-for-reminders/id1604744014?mt=12
I'm the author of this app btw.